# php random order from a foreach

Tags: php, random, foreach, shuffle

I have some foreach, this could work well

```
foreach ($umm as $data) {
        echo '<img src="'.$data->picture.'" />';
        echo  $data->id;
}
```

Now I want shuffle the foreach. I tried:

```
foreach (shuffle($umm) as $data) {
        echo '<img src="'.$data->picture.'" />';
        echo  $data->id;
}
```

AND

```
foreach ($umm as $data) {
        $rand_pic[] = $data->picture;
        $rand_id[] = $data->id;
}
$ran = shuffle($rand_id);
foreach($ran as $new){
    echo '<img src="'.$new->picture.'" width="100" />';
    echo $new->id;
}
```

All these caused `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` in second `foreach`. How to random order from a foreach?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation for `shuffle()`](http://php.net/shuffle). It takes a *reference* to an array and shuffles it in place. So you need to use it on the array, then iterate:

```
shuffle($umm);

foreach ($umm as $data) {
        echo '<img src="'.$data->picture.'" />';
        echo  $data->id;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[shuffle()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) returns a boolean - you pass the array by reference

Try this:

```
shuffle($umm);
foreach($umm as $new){
    echo '<img src="'.$new->picture.'" width="100" />';
    echo $new->id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try This Shuffle:

```html
<?php 
   shuffle($umm);
   foreach($umm as $key => $value): ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $value->picture; ?>" alt="<?php echo $value->title;?>" />
 <?php echo $value->id;?>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```